# I'm thinking of a number

Tags: number-property

The unusual thing about this number is that the most common phrases that use it are wrong. That is, while someone may often say there are X As in a B, the actual number is not X.

What number am I thinking of?

Hint 1:

> "There are X As in a B", but almost every B contains at least X + 2 As.

Hint 2:

> "There are X Cs in a D" but a D always contains between X + 0.1 and X + 0.3 Cs

Comment: It looks like the hints are necessary for the actual puzzle here. Otherwise I could just answer rot13(**n pbhcyr**, fvapr jura jr fnl "n pbhcyr guvatf" jr hfhnyyl qba'g zrna rknpgyl gjb).

Comment: @EKons But rot13(n zneevrq pbhcyr) is correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A number which fits is

> $52$

Hint 1:

> There are $52$ cards in a deck, but almost all standard decks are sold with an extra two or three jokers, as some card games need these.

Hint 2:

> It's said there are $52$ weeks in a year, but a year has 365 or 366 days and,
>  $365/7 \approx 52.14...$ and $366/7 \approx 52.28...$